# Speech recognition box that can act as a keyboard

Tags: keyboards

I am looking for a device that can perform speech recognition and connect to a computer so that it acts as a keyboard. E.g., if I say "hello", the device should send the keys <kbd>h</kbd>,  <kbd>e</kbd>  , <kbd>l</kbd> , <kbd>l</kbd> , <kbd>o</kbd> to the computer.

I am aware of [VoxCube](https://redd.it/5p3uxb) but it is currently just a prototype and not being sold.

Any price is fine.